# ffmpeg with rtsp input libx264 decoding error

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, rtsp

We currently have a rtsp stream , and we are trying to show it in a webbrowser. we have used node-ffmpeg and getting the stream from device and publishing it using websocket. The stream we are getting from device used libx264 as encoder, but we are facing an error.

This is what we are trying to achieve.

```js
const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
  '-i', 'rtsp://IP_ADDRESS:PORT_NUMBER/test',
  '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
  '-c:v','libx264',
  '-f' ,'flv',
  '-b:v','1000k',
  '-r', '30',
  '-'
]);
```

The error showing is: "**Unknown encoder libx264**".

This is what we tried as an alternative and working but facing another issue.

```js
const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
  '-i', 'rtsp://IP_ADDRESS:PORT_NUMBER/test',
  '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
  '-c:v','mpeg1video',
  '-f' ,'mpegts',
  '-b:v','1000k',
  '-r', '30',
  '-'
]);
```

we have used the encoder "**mpeg1video**" and the format "**mpegts**". The stream is showing but since it is not h264 encoder the stream showing pixels is not compatible with the resolution, the Stream we are getting has "**yuv420p**" pixel format.The error we are getting is:

> [h264 @ 0x563e3a9d16c0] error while decoding MB 47 16, bytestream -19
>
> [h264 @ 0x563e3a9d16c0] concealing 6242 DC, 6242 AC, 6242 MV errors in
> I frame
>
> frame=30477 fps= 17 q=31.0 size=  300142kB time=00:29:47.96
> bitrate=1375.2kbits/s speed=   1x      [rtsp @ 0x563e3a991e60] max
> delay reached. need to consume packet
>
> [rtsp @ 0x563e3a991e60] RTP: missed 6 packets

We are showing the stream in html in cavas player, we are receiving the stream through websocket and showing it.

```
var player = new JSMpeg.Player('ws://localhost:9004', {
    canvas: canvas,
    disableGl: true,
    videoBufferSize: 1024*1024*8
});
```

Please tell if anyone have the solution for this.